# Extjs + Asp.Net LINQ + webservice

Tags: asp.net, linq, web-services, extjs4.1

I am working with ExtJs 4.1.and **I want to develop basic gridpanel application in extjs which display data from linq through WebService** I am not using asp.net MVC. so how can i display??

I tried to find solution from following code but didn't find success.

**grid.js**

```
Ext.application({
    launch: function() {
        // Model definition and remote store (used Ext examples data)
        Ext.define('ForumThread', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['countryId', 'countryName'],
            idProperty: 'countryId'
        });

         var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        pageSize: 20,
        model: 'ForumThread',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '../reports/test.asmx/display',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             //url: '/grid.json',
            reader: {                
                type: 'json',
                method: "GET",
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            }
        }
    });

        // Define grid that will automatically restore its selection after store reload
        Ext.define('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

        });

        // Create instance of previously defined persistant selection grid panel
        var grid = Ext.create('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
            autoscroll: true,
            height: 300,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            //region: 'center',
            store: store,
            multiSelect: true, // Delete this if you only need single row selection
            stateful: true,
            forceFit: true,
            loadMask: false,
            viewConfig: {
                stripeRows: true
            },
            columns:[{
                id: 'countryId',
                text: "countryId",
                dataIndex: 'countryId',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: false
            },{
                text: "countryName",
                dataIndex: 'countryName',
                width: 70,
                align: 'right',
                sortable: true
            } ]
        });
    }
});
```

**test.asmx**

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json , UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public string display()
    {
        country obj = new country();
        //return obj.SelectAll();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(obj.SelectAll());
    }
```

**but i am getting following error in firebug**
[image]

Comment: This error has nothing to do with Extjs. you've got a serializing error (circular reference) on the .net side.

Comment: @CD yes i know its error on asp.net side. and I also know why this error come[country table is linked with state then state table is linked with city n city table is linked with employee n employee is linked with appoinmnet like vice anywhere it will found (circuler refrence)].. but i didn't know how to solve this. i had tried alot things but didn't found

Comment: try to mark one related navigation properties with `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute..

Comment: if i am writing [XmlIgnore] above webservice display method it will give me following error. **Attribute 'XmlIgnore' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param, return' declarations.**

Comment: you should mark the properties with the attribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx

Comment: @CD as you suggest me **mark property as ScriptIgnoreAttribute** but i am confused where to mark.. I am using linq. i have to change in linq cs file?? can you please give me simple example so i will understand.

Comment: @CD i had update my question please review my question